# Assets.car generated by Xcode 10 is larger than Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

I create a framework target and add a media.xcassets into it. (to avoid app icon & launcher image.) This is the info of media.xcassets:

[image]

When I use Xcode 10 GM to build this framework, I get a assets.car more than 20MB!
And if I use Xcode 9.4 to build this framework, the size of assets.car is 16MB.

Then I try to change the deploy target version of framework, and get these results:

[image]

I want to keep size of my app smaller. So should I avoid to use image assets? Is this a bug of Xcode 10?

Comment: Xcode 10 release version still has this "issue".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108467 will help, it seems that Apple will optimize the assets.car file when your app is ready for sale in AppStore.